# How do you create a subscription with a trial period with the Paypal Javascript SDK?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Is there a way to create a subscription with a trial period using the Paypal Javascript SDK? Alternatively is there a way to customize a subscription (after it was created via the Paypal Javascript SDK - button)?

Creating multiple plans with different trial or discounts is not a good option as my implementation is meant to have any number or type of discounts. I'd rather choose to have only 2 plans: one monthly and yearly and then apply a discount or a trial to the subscription if at all possible.

My code is the standard for creating a subscription (a product - v1/catalogs/products - and a plan - v1/billing/plans - have already been created so I am only passing the PLAN_ID to JS):

```
<script>
      paypal.Buttons({
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.subscription.create({
            'plan_id': 'PLAN_ID' // Creates the subscription
          });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID); // Optional message given to subscriber
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Renders the PayPal button
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd rather choose to have only 2 plans: one monthly and yearly and then apply a discount or a trial to the subscription if at all possible.

This cannot be done. The plan specifies the billing amounts and times.

The only amount that can be set at subscription time is added shipping.

Plans can be created dynamically via the Subscriptions API's Plans resource group, [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create)

Comment: So if I have a certain number of different types of discounts (including different free trial options; Eg. 1st month free, 1st month at 50% etc.), it means I have to create an equal number of plans?

Comment: It may be that I have the plan logic wrong; If two customers subscribe for the exact same thing, then do I need to create two different plans, besides the two subscriptions?

Comment: If they are subscribing for the same thing, use the same plan for both.